# Debugging errors of SAGA interpolation algorithms in QGIS Processing?

Tags: qgis, interpolation, saga, qgis-processing

I encounter recurrent problems with the geoalgorithms that perform interpolations.
No matter what technique I use I end with the following errors. As stated in the OGR tab QGIS 2.0 is unable to open a file in C drive.
I have very little IT background so the message error is meaningless.

Is there anybody able to decrypt the message and solve the problem?

[image]

[image]

here this is the algorithm i used

[image]

Comment: Try copying everything in the log screen just behind the window. From here I can already see "Error" just below GDAL, so it contains pointers as to where things go wrong.

Comment: I don't know I have understood properly but this is what I can read

Comment: SAGA execution console output

C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\bin>set SAGA=C:\Program Files\QGIS Dufour\apps\saga

C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\bin>set SAGA_MLB=C:\Program Files\QGIS Dufour\apps\saga\modules

C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\bin>PATH=PATH;C:\Program Files\QGIS Dufour\apps\saga;C:\Program Files\QGIS Dufour\apps\saga\modules

C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\bin>saga_cmd shapes_polygons "Polygon Centroids" -POLYGONS "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\tests\data\polygons.shp" -CENTROIDS "D:\Users\ilango13\AppData\Local\Temp\processing\a9fccaf022ae41298b805964ab7fe6b0\CENTROIDS.shp"

Comment: library path: C:\Program Files\QGIS Dufour\apps\saga\modules\shapes_polygons.dll
library name: Shapes - Polygons
module name : Polygon Centroids
author      : (c) 2003 by O.Conrad

Comment: Load shapes: C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\tests\data\polygons.shp...




Parameters


Polygons: polygons
Centroids: Centroids
Centroids for each part: no

Comment: processing.runalg("saga:polygoncentroids","C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\\processing\\tests\\data\\polygons.shp",False,None)

Comment: my question is...why is looking for polygon centroids?

Comment: Can you make a screen copy of the plugin dialogue before it starts computing?

Comment: ok how can i add an image in this comment?

Comment: Andre, got it. It is in the question i posted. Thanks!

Comment: Not exactly an answer but two ideas : - Cellsize of 10 means 10°. Can you test with 0,001 ? - Can you test without output name ? SAGA prefers "sdat".

Answer (score 3):

You get this message whenever the SAGA process is stuck somewhere, and therefor the resulting file is not created. The message tells you also that SAGA is correctly installed, so it must have to do with the data, or the parameters you entered.

Usefull hints may come from the log, which is behind the error message box.

Just a guess: Are all your layers in the same CRS? That is, when switching On-the-fly reprojection **off**, are they still in the same place? This is mandatory for any SAGA algorithm that uses more than one layer.

Comment: Andre, in QGIS i loaded only one file so there wasn't a problem with CRS (the CRS is EPSG:4326 - WGS84). The "interesting" bit is that If I run SAGA from its gui.exe I manage to have a correct map. thus the algorithm works by sure and I am using correct parameters. For an unknown reason doesn't work in QGIS and gets stuck somewhere. It would be great to know where and why. thanks